Getting Abstract type GenericBillingAccount must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field GenericBillingAccount.billingAccounts
"message": "Can't resolve '/customer/billingAccounts[0]'. Abstract type 'GenericBillingAccount' must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field '[GenericBillingAccount].billingAccounts'. Could not determine the exact type of 'GenericBillingAccount'",
GraphQL query :
query customer($identityId: String!) {
  customer(identityId: $identityId){
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email
      billingAccounts{          
        __typename                      
            ... on MobileBillingAccount {
                accountNumber,
                bills{                                                                   
                    billAmountGbp
                    isCombinedBill
                }
            }
            ... on BroadbandBillingAccount {
                accountNumber
            }               
                    
        }
  }
}


Getting following response when hit the API :
{ "errors": [ { "message": "Can't resolve '/customer/billingAccounts[0]'. Abstract type 'GenericBillingAccount' must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field '[GenericBillingAccount].billingAccounts'. Could not determine the exact type of 'GenericBillingAccount'", "path": [ "customer", "billingAccounts", 0 ], "extensions": { "classification": "DataFetchingException" } }, { "message": "Can't resolve '/customer/billingAccounts[1]'. Abstract type 'GenericBillingAccount' must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field '[GenericBillingAccount].billingAccounts'. Could not determine the exact type of 'GenericBillingAccount'", "path": [ "customer", "billingAccounts", 1 ], "extensions": { "classification": "DataFetchingException" } } ] }
Resolver
@Controller
public class GenericBillingAccountResolver implements GraphQLResolver<List<GenericBillingAccountModel>> {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericBillingAccountResolver.class);

    private final DataLoaderServiceLocator dataLoaderServiceLocator;

    public GenericBillingAccountResolver(DataLoaderServiceLocator dataLoaderServiceLocator) {
        this.dataLoaderServiceLocator = dataLoaderServiceLocator;
    }

    @SchemaMapping(typeName = "Customer", field = "billingAccounts")
    public CompletableFuture<List<? extends GenericBillingAccountModel>>     billingAccounts(DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
        GraphQLContext graphQLContext = env.getGraphQlContext();
        String identityId = graphQLContext.get("identityId").toString();
        LOG.info("GenericBillingAccountResolver is invoked");
        return dataLoaderServiceLocator.billingAccountDataLoader().load(identityId);
    }
}

#BatchLoader
@NotNull
    @Override
    protected Supplier<List<? extends GenericBillingAccountModel>> loadSingleItem(@NotNull String identityId) {

        List<GenericBillingAccountModel> response = new ArrayList<>();
        return () -> {
            ResponseEntity<BillingAccountsDto> billingAccounts = apigeeBillingAccountCollaborator.getBillingAccounts(identityId);
            List<BillingAccountDto> billingAccountList = billingAccounts.getBody().getBillingAccounts();

            billingAccountList.forEach(billingAccount -> {
                if (billingAccount.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("EXC")) {
                    // call to excallibure
                    MobileBillingAccountModel mobileBillingAccountModel = new MobileBillingAccountModel();
                    mobileBillingAccountModel.setAccountNumber(billingAccount.getId());
                    ResponseEntity<MobileBillsDto> mobileBillDtos = apigeeMobileBillsCollaborator.getMobileBills(billingAccount.getId());
                    mobileBillingAccountModel.setBills(mobileBillsConverter.convert(mobileBillDtos.getBody().getBills()));
                    response.add(mobileBillingAccountModel);
                } else if (billingAccount.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CCP") ){
                    // call to broadband System

                    BroadbandBillingAccountModel broadbandBillingAccountModel = new BroadbandBillingAccountModel();
                    broadbandBillingAccountModel.setAccountNumber(billingAccount.getId());

                }
            });
            return response;
        };
    }
}

#schema.graphql
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
    customer(
        identityId: String!
    ): Customer!
}

type Customer {
    email: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    billingAccounts: [GenericBillingAccount]
}


interface GenericBillingAccount {
    accountNumber: String
    bills: [Bill!]!
}

type MobileBillingAccount implements GenericBillingAccount {
    accountNumber: String
    bills: [MobileBill!]!
}

type BroadbandBillingAccount implements GenericBillingAccount {
    accountNumber: String
    bills: [BroadbandBill!]!
}

interface Bill{
    billAmountGbp: String!
    billIssueDate: Date!
}

type MobileBill implements Bill{
    invoiceNo: String!
    billAmountGbp: String!
 
}

type BroadbandBill implements Bill{
    billAmountGbp: String!
    billIssueDate: Date!
}

"""
Calendar date type in ISO-8601 format - yyyy-MM-dd (like 1970-01-13)
"""
scalar Date

#CustomerModel class
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CustomerModel implements Serializable {

    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<GenericBillingAccountModel> billingAccount;
}

#GenericBillingAccountModel

`@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GenericBillingAccountModel implements Serializable {

    private String accountNumber;
    private List<? extends BillModel> bills;
}`

`
